# Use of data within a plist in Xcode for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, lookup

Hoping someone out there can help me. I'm very new to iOS app development and am actually trying to put something together for a careers day event at a local school.

The background is that I want to be able to test students' ability to accurately process and input data.

To test this, I want an app I will deploy onto iPads for them to try during the day. Very simple stuff (I think!)

So far I know how to create my app, put the input boxes in and all linked up and have worked out how to test that the input into the boxes is correct against a hard coded value in code like this:

```
  self.DealID = self.DealIDEntry.text;
    NSString *Check1 = @"No";
    NSString *DealIDString = self.DealID;
    if ([DealIDString length] == 0) {
        Check1 = @"No Deal ID Entered";
    }
    if([self.DealID isEqual: @"12345678"]) {
        Check1 = @"Yes";
    }
    self.DealIDCheck.text = Check1;
```

What I want though, is to have a table of possible DealIDs, each with 5-6 bits of associated data (customer, currency etc) and then when the student enters the deal ID and what will hopefully be the correct customer, currency etc the app should check by doing a "lookup" of the DealID in the plist and checking that the customer value is correct for that DealID.

I've tried doing this by means of a dictionary:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *pListpath = [bundle pathForResource:@"TestTable" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListpath];



self.CustomerName = self.CustomerNameEntry.text;
    NSString *Check2 = @"No";
    NSDictionary *DealID = [dict valueForKey:self.DealID];
    NSString *CustomerNameString = self.CustomerName;
    if ([CustomerNameString length] == 0) {
        Check2 = @"No Customer Name Entered";
    }
    if([self.CustomerName isEqual: [DealID objectForKey:@"CustomerName"]]) {
        Check2 = @"Yes";
    }
    self.CustomerNameCheck.text = Check2;
```

Sadly it's not working, I suspect either I don't know how to correctly load the plist (or test if it's loaded) or I've just done it wrong!

Edit 2 - Thanks to Matt's help below, I now have this code to load my plist as a directory of directories and can query it for the relevant object for a given subdirectory. Thanks again Matt!

```
//This loads the array of data
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"TestTable" ofType:@"plist"];
    //Make large Dictionary
    NSDictionary *TradeTable = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSLog(@"The count: %i", [TradeTable count]);
    //Create relevant sub directory
    NSDictionary *query = [TradeTable valueForKey:@"12345678"];
    NSLog(@"The count: %i", [query count]);
    //Query that subdirectory for the object in question
    NSString *name = [query objectForKey:@"CustomerName"];
    NSLog(name);
```

For anyone interested, my plist now looks like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>12345678</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CustomerID</key>
        <integer>98765</integer>
        <key>CustomerName</key>
        <string>BigBank</string>
        <key>CustomerBank</key>
        <string>LittleBank</string>
        <key>AmountinCCY</key>
        <integer>75000</integer>
        <key>CCY</key>
        <string>GBP</string>
        <key>AmountinUSD</key>
        <integer>115000</integer>
        <key>Date</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Points</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>12345679</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CustomerID</key>
        <integer>98754</integer>
        <key>CustomerName</key>
        <string>CarShop</string>
        <key>CustomerBank</key>
        <string>BigBank</string>
        <key>AmountinCCY</key>
        <integer>25123</integer>
        <key>CCY</key>
        <string>EUR</string>
        <key>AmountinUSD</key>
        <integer>27000</integer>
        <key>Date</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Points</key>
        <integer>4</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Sorry for being wordy, just wanted to make sure I gave as much info as I could.

Very much appreciate anyone's assistance.
Phill

Comment: basically you want to search Dealid in your pList right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plist you've shown will load as an NSArray of NSDictionary objects. So load it with NSArray `arrayWithContentsOfFile:`; then you walk the NSArray until you find the NSDictionary you want.

You are using `[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListpath]`, but the result (your `dict`) is nil because this is *not* a dictionary, it's an array. The docs on `initWithContentsOfFile:` predict exactly this:

> Return Value: An initialized dictionary... *or nil if ... the contents of the file are an invalid representation of a dictionary.*

(My italics)

Well, that's your problem. The contents of the file are an invalid representation of a dictionary, because they are in fact a valid representation of an array.

Now, I'm not saying that an array of dictionaries is the best way to store your data. I think a dictionary of dictionaries would have been much better (because then you could grab the right subdictionary instantly by some master key, such as the DealID). But, for whatever reason, that's not how you stored your data. You stored it as an array, and you must now retrieve it as an array.

EDIT: What I'm suggesting is that you use the value of the deal ID as the key for the subdictionaries. Like this:

```
Dictionary
    key: 12345678
    value: a whole nother dictionary with everything *else* about that answer
    ---
    key: 12345679
    value: a whole nother dictionary with everything *else* about that answer
    ---
    etc.
```

So you start with your big dictionary of dictionaries (`d`), now `d[someDealId]` is the correct subdictionary (`subd`), and now you can get `subd[@"customerName"]` or any other value by key. This seems to me to be exactly the sort of "lookup" you were describing.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I got the array to load but will switch to a dictionary of dictionaries as you suggest. That should get me over hurdle number one. Number two would be how to then search that dictionary of dictionaries by DealID to return say the CustomerID for a given DealID. I miss vlookups in excel! :)

Comment: But if it's a dictionary of dictionaries properly set up, there will be no search. I'll modify my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks Matt, working like a charm now I think! I've updated my question above to reflect what I've done based on your most helpful answer.